# Kotlin: how to resorve this déclaration off View

Tags: kotlin, view, textview

in my code Kotlin
everytime I have Error in

val fab = findViewById<**FloatingActionButton**>(R.id.fab)

val txtv1= findViewById<**TextView**>(R.id.textV1)

I change it :
val fab = findViewById(R.id.fab) as **FloatingActionButton**

val fab = findViewById(R.id.textV1) as **TextView**

everytime error in AdsView, Button,.................

Comment: If this is about Android, it might help to add that as a tag.  It might also help if you could give details about the error you're getting.

Comment: Taking some wild assumptions that this code is in a Fragment on Android. `findViewById` is a function of View, so you need to prepend these calls with `requireView().` But it is cleaner to use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Comment: not enough information to infer parameter T in fun findViewById(id: Int): T!